# Is it possible to stop people from associating things with me on Facebook without my permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, permissions, facebook-tags

On Facebook, it's possible by default for someone's friends to tag him in a photo without his permission. Is there any way for a user to stop his friends from doing that, or to at least require his approval before the tag becomes public?

I don't know if there are other places where people can have their information shared without permission, but if so, this question applies to those places too.

Comment: It's high time that facebook should include the functionality of disabling photo tagging from some of the friends. I desperately need it. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by going to your [Privacy Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy).

- Select Edit Settings under "How Tags Work"
  [image: Privacy Settings]
- Click Off next to Timeline Review
  [image: How Tags Work]
- Review the information about Timeline Review and select Enabled from the dropdown.
  [image: Timeline Review]

Comment: This controls whether the photo will appear on your timeline, but the real question is whether it will appear in your friends' News Feed.  If a friend tags you will the photo still be sent immediately to all your friends' News Feed or does that happen only if and when you approve it to appear on your timeline?

Comment: Even if it *does* stop items from showing up on friend's feeds (not sure if it does), it doesn't stop the notifications of tagged photos. Oh, so much spam... Sigh.

Answer (score 9):

You can stop others notifications of photos you are tagged in appearing.

Go to http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&ref=mb and select "Customise settings".

On that page there's an option in the "Things others share" section:

> Photos and videos I'm tagged in

Select the drop down and pick "Customise". You then get this dialog

[image]

Select "Only me" for "Make this visible to" and only you will get notifications.

Comment: Not perfect, but it looks like this is the best option facebook offers.

Comment: and what If I don't want notifications from the photos I am tagged in?

Comment: Facebook has brought out a new [control feature](https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=10150251867797131)

Comment: There's no more a "Things others share" section.

Comment: @ruda.almeida - that's the problem with ever changing applications.  This answer is over two years old and was correct at the time of posting.

Comment: @ChrisF Is there any substitute or similar for it?

Comment: @ruda.almeida - I don't know. I haven't checked recently. Is the accepted answer wrong now too?

Comment: @ChrisF Not exactly, it is right, and it works. The case is: I need to stop **one single user** from tagging me in many different photos over time (SPAM), I want to prevent a certaing user from tagging me in photos, whithout blocking or unfriending him. I have the Timeline Review enabled, as in the accepted question, but it doesn't stop the notifications -- I had made a question in this site, then deleted it upon finding this one, but maybe I'll re-add it, because the accepted answer is not what I need.

Comment: @ruda.almeida - That does sound like a different question to this. Undelete but link back to this one explaining why it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prevent the tag from happening, but you can control who gets notified of it in their home feed, ie "Person was tagged in an album".

Account > Privacy Settings > Customize Settings > Things Others Share > Photos and Video I'm tagged in.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove yourself from a photo tag, it can't be added again unless **you** do it.

Comment: Yes, but it works just on **that** specific photo. I have a friend who tags me constantly in photos I'm not in.