# Automatic Untagging in Facebook Photos Uploaded by a Specific Person

Tags: facebook, photos

I maintain very tight privacy options on Facebook, and I want my Facebook experience to be friend-centric. Is there someway I can automatically untag myself from every photo someone (say a family member) uploads with myself tagged?

Comment: Could you ask your parents to never tag you? Or do you not want to appear rude - if so, that is understandable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to stop people from associating things with me on facebook without my permission?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/is-it-possible-to-stop-people-from-associating-things-with-me-on-facebook-without)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it doesn't look like you can automatically untag photos of yourself from specific users.

From: [How to Block Facebook Photos of Yourself](http://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/05/05/how-to-block-facebook-photos-of-yourself/)

> **There is no way to prevent someone from tagging a photo with either your username, or your name as a tag. What’s possible is you can prevent other users from searching for photos of you.**

Also:

> Facebook emailed me back stating that there are no security settings to prevent anyone from tagging you in the first place

**The only thing you can really do is to make all tagged photos of you hidden to others:**

> First visit your profile privacy page and modify the setting next to “Photos Tagged of You”. > Select the option which says “Customize…” and a box like the one pictured below will pop up.
>   Select the option “Only Me” and then “None of My Networks” if you would like to keep all tagged photos private.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove several tags at once, you can go into the activity log page, check the boxes of the photos you want untagged, and a button will appear in the upper right that says "report/remove tags." Click that button and select the radio button for untagging.