# Prevent People from tagging me on facebook photo

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to stop people from associating things with me on facebook without my permission?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/is-it-possible-to-stop-people-from-associating-things-with-me-on-facebook-without)

How do I prevent people or applications from tagging me to photo? or better yet, set all new tagged photo to private and only after approval then it goes public.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can.

Only friends can tag you in Photos. Some Facebook applications which your friends use tag you in photos . I dont think there is a way yet on Facebook. Please contact Facbook.