# Blocking a person from tagging you in photos

Tags: facebook

Out of my 600+ contacts on Facebook, there is a single one who's constantly tagging me on photos I'm not present. I don't want to block or unfriend him. I know it is possible to block app/game invites/requests from other users. Is there a way to block specific friends from tagging you in photos?

PS: this is not a duplicate of this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/is-it-possible-to-stop-people-from-associating-things-with-me-on-facebook-withou/3318#comment27517_3318), I have the Timeline Review enabled, but still, I don't want the many notifications showing up and manually having to review and remove his tags.

Comment: ....... how about you just tell that person to stop tagging you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Comment: Then you are at a stalemate mate because that's the option Facebook gives in their report a photo form.

Comment: Isn't there a way to create a contact list, limit its rights and then add that person to the list?

Comment: @AlexInParis Interesting approach, I will give it a try.

Comment: You can put items up for review when you're tagged in them. At least then it wouldn't be public first.

Comment: @Dez Isn't it the same as Timeline Review? I have it enabled already, I get the notifications telling me to check it, but I don't like the many notifications, hence my request.

Comment: heh, yes... it is. didn't read that far apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not a built-in setting in Facebook to stop a single friend from tagging you. But to solve this problem I suggest you the following:

1. **Ask him** amicably not to tag you! Trust me, this is the best way to solve the issue!
2. **Remove tags each time** after she/he tags you. She/he might understand you're feeling good with her/his tagging job!
3. For each photo or post you're tagged in, you can choose to "**Unfollow Updates**", in order to not receive notifications *from that specific post or photo* anymore. Other users will continue to see the tag and the post might show up on their newsfeed.
4. You definitely know that you can **[review tags from friends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22519/30054)** before being posted on your timeline. Even if you don't allow the tags to show up on **your** timeline, or even if you don't review the tags, other users will continue to see the tag and the post might show up on their newsfeed -- this controls only what shows up on **your timeline**.
5. Also you can define **what people can see** the photos you are tagged in!

What you've asked here sounds to be a required need among Facebook users and why don't you contact Facebook and ask them to provide users with this feature?

Comment: In option (3) you mean I can unfollow updates from this user's tagged photos, or from tags from everyone on facebook?

Comment: Actually this option is used for post and not for a user. It means each time you're tagged in a photo, you must unfollow updates from that photo.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer. It does **not** solves my problem, unfortunately, but might solve the problems of other users of this site, and apparently there's no fix for my issue =/

Comment: You're right about this ruda and there is no direct fix for your issue.